# Byte-buddy and cglib not available in Spock test

Tags: unit-testing, gradle, groovy, dependencies, spock

I started playing around with Spock testing framework and my `build.gradle` dependencies section looks like this:

```
dependencies {
    testCompile "org.spockframework:spock-core:1.3-groovy-2.5"
}
```

I have a (useless) Spock test that requires creation of a stub:

```
def 'A test that will fail'() {
    given: ''
    def random = Stub(Random)
}
```

When launched, the test fails with the given error:

> CannotCreateMockException: Cannot create mock for class java.util.Random. Mocking of non-interface types requires a code generation library. Please put an up-to-date version of byte-buddy or cglib-nodep on the class path.

This error is mentioned in [Spock documentation](http://spockframework.org/spock/docs/1.3/interaction_based_testing.html#Stubs) and it's caused by cglib or byte-buddy not being available at runtime.

Considering that [spock-core's pom lists both byte-buddy and cglib as compile dependencies](https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.spockframework/spock-core/1.3-groovy-2.5/jar), why are they not retained at runtime? In other words, why do we need to explicitly add the following runtime dependency to our build.gradle file?

```
testRuntime "net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy:1.9.3"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because both (*byte-buddy* and *cglib-nodep*) are marked as `<optional>true</optional>`, where from Gradle point of view they are as `compileOnly` dependencies - see: https://blog.gradle.org/introducing-compile-only-dependencies

> Compile-only dependencies are distinctly different than regular
>   compile dependencies. They are not included on the runtime classpath
>   and they are non-transitive, meaning they are not included in
>   dependent projects.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I didn't know about compile only dependencies!!

Answer (score 1):

They are optional dependencies, so you need to include them if you want that functionality

https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-optional-and-excludes-dependencies.html